# Already downloaded app re-downloading on iTunes

Tags: itunes, games

[image]

I just downloaded a game on iTunes name Warhammer 40,000: Deathwatch. Now this app is downloading again on iTunes! What should I do to cancel this re-downloading? It's a big size app and I don't want to download again. How can I cancel this download?

Comment: Where do you download the game, on your iPhone/iPad or on your computer? Are you sure it isn't just an update which gets loaded?

Comment: It's not an update. First time downloaded on iTunes and then next day the app started re-downloading again. Can't find any way to cancel that download.